# Which music style is King Herod's song supposed to be?

Tags: identify-this-genre

In *Jesus Christ Superstar*, King Herod's song has a very particular music style.

I see also that it slightly changes from one version of the musical to another.

**Which music style is King Herod's song in 1973 *Jesus Christ Superstar*?** Is it the same style in other versions, like the 2018's?

---

Youtube videos as reference:
[1973 version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z9ALiADrJro),
[2018 version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8fs9n4azYJE)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's [**Ragtime**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ragtime), though there's a dependence on how much the piano dominates the arrangement over the horns. Once the horns & woods [clarinet etc] start to take over, then it becomes more **[Trad Jazz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trad_jazz)**, which some might term Dixieland. [If I remember my musical history correctly, dixieland doesn't have to have a piano at all, it's sometimes banjo instead.]

A 1920's early jazz style, epitomised by [Scott Joplin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott_Joplin). Its trademark is [stride piano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stride_(music)) where the left hand is busy playing octaves in large leaps & takes quite some skill to perform

Popularised additionally in such movies as [The Sting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sting), which also brought the style back to a modern-day audience.

It may not be complete coincidence as the two movies were popular at the same time - JCS was written in about 1969/70 so the producers of The Sting may have heard it used in that & brought it even more to the fore.
Perhaps just zeitgeist.

Just for fun, a bit of live ragtime - this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H9GcA1rltoQ) is a friend of mine, Paul "Harry" Harris, playing The Beatles' Lady Madonna at Abbey Road Studios... on the original piano.